# "undefined is not an object" when create multidivisional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I wrote the code:

```
    var from = 6;
    var io_arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    var mem_arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    var cpu_arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

    var x = new Array(io_arr.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++) {
        x[i] = new Array(4);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= io_arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
            if(j == 0) {
                x[i][j] = from + i - 1;
            }
            if (j == 1) {
                x[i][j] = io_arr[i];
            }
            if (j == 2) {
                x[i][j] = mem_arr[i];
            }
            if (j == 3) {
                x[i][j] = cpu_arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Had the error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x[i][j] = io_arr[i]')
```

What's wrong with this? I'm very new to JS, so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Comment: It's most likely the last iteration of `for (var i = 1; i <= io_arr.length; i++)`. `i` will equal `io_arr.length` which is beyond the last index

Comment: The mixture of `for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++)` and `for (var i = 1; i <= io_arr.length; i++)` is the problem.  In fact, you only need the one loop.  Get rid of the first closing brace and the declaration of the second loop.

Comment: Phil, thanks - that works! I should be more attentive. Rob Lyndon, I did't get your idea. I separated creation to keep the first raw of    x    empty.

Comment: OK, understood.  There is another way to do that.  I'll add an answer to illustrate it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:
`for (var i = 1; i <= io_arr.length; i++)` needs to be: `for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++)`
Or is there a specific reason why you modified this in the second `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

`for (var i = 1; i <= io_arr.length; i++) {`

is wrong, the first index is 0 not 1. An you are going too far, as the last index is not the value of `io_arr.length` but one smaller then the length (because it's starting at 0 ;) )
This should then work:

`for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++) {`

I checked the Code by changing this line, and it does not throw any error. This is just some programming basics you will have to get used to

Answer (score 0):

So my original suggestion (in the comments) was to perform both operations in the same loop.  That would allow you to get rid of two lines of code.  So

```
var x = new Array(io_arr.length);
for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++) {
    x[i] = new Array(4);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= io_arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        if(j == 0) {
            x[i][j] = from + i - 1;
        }
        if (j == 1) {
            x[i][j] = io_arr[i];
        }
        if (j == 2) {
            x[i][j] = mem_arr[i];
        }
        if (j == 3) {
            x[i][j] = cpu_arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

would be replaced be

```
var x = new Array(io_arr.length);
for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++) {
    x[i] = new Array(4);
    for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        if(j == 0) {
            x[i][j] = from + i - 1;
        }
        if (j == 1) {
            x[i][j] = io_arr[i];
        }
        if (j == 2) {
            x[i][j] = mem_arr[i];
        }
        if (j == 3) {
            x[i][j] = cpu_arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that you want the first row of `x` to be empty.  You can do that in a single loop by adding an `if` statement inside the loop:

```
var x = new Array(io_arr.length);
for (var i = 0; i < io_arr.length; i++) {
    x[i] = new Array(4);
    if (x === 0) continue;
    for (var j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        if(j === 0) {
            x[i][j] = from + i - 1;
        }
        if (j === 1) {
            x[i][j] = io_arr[i];
        }
        if (j === 2) {
            x[i][j] = mem_arr[i];
        }
        if (j === 3) {
            x[i][j] = cpu_arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you your desired answer.

Note that I've changed `==` to `===`, which should always be the preferred choice, because `==` performs weird conversions, and Javascript purists don't like it.